# How to query sibling territories?

Tags: account, territory-management, territory

How to query for accounts in child territories? I can't seem to find any documentation for this.

I had posted a [similar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65185/unable-to-view-accounts-from-sibling-territories) question, but got no response.

Any reference would be great too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an algorithm to get the territory for an account:

Algorithm (Pseudo Code):

1. Query AccountShare object where AccountId = Trigger.New (Account Ids)
   where RowCause = 'Territory' (Note: If Account has assigned via Territory Assignment Rules).
   where RowCause = 'TerritoryManual' (Note: If Account has assigned via “Manually Assigned Accounts” related list on Territory detail page or AccountShare record has created in Apex Code).
2. Query Group object where Id = AccountShare.UserOrGroupId
3. Query Territory object where Id = Group.RelatedId
4. Query UserTerritory object where Id = Territory.UserId

Reference: [Sheikh Abrar Ul Haq @ salesforce dev forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008w0uIAA)